# JavaFX TextArea wraps text, but it shouldn't

Tags: java, javafx, scene, scenegraph

Ok, I'm a javafx newbe and just try to build my own java IDE.

The IDE has a view ("Start" tab) in which you can create and edit classes and a debug view ("Debug" tab) in which this class can be debugged. (For debugging im using the JDPA).

The "Start" view is a simple tabpane (classtabPane) consisting several tabs in the center area of ​​the root borderpane.

The "Debug" view consists a splitpane which assigned the classTabPane and other nodes, when the views are changed.

The switch between these views is realized by another tabpane, which is integrated in the top area of ​​the root borderpane.

Each class is a separate tab in which a textarea is embedded. Each text of these textAreas should NOT be wrapped (setWrapText(false)).

At a view-change (from start to debug), the nodes to be displayed (classTabpane OR splitPane that classTabPane has assigned) get assigned to the center area of the root borderpane.

**The problem is when I change the views (from start to debug), the text is wrapped in a textarea, which should not actually happen.
But after clicking in the textarea, the text becomes unwrapped.**

Does anyone have a notion what it might be that the text is wrapped in a view change?

If any useful information is missing, just say. 
I will add it immediately.

Picture examples can be found under the code snippet

```
private void selectDebugView(String _id) {
    SplitPane splitPane_horizontal;
    SplitPane splitPane_vertical;
    switch (_id) {
    case "debugView1":
        splitPane_vertical = new SplitPane();
        splitPane_horizontal = new SplitPane();
        splitPane_vertical.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        splitPane_horizontal.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        splitPane_vertical.getItems().addAll(debugInspectorTabPane, consoleDebugTabPane);
        splitPane_horizontal.getItems().addAll(classTabPane, splitPane_vertical);
        borderPane_root.setCenter(splitPane_horizontal);
        break;
    case "debugView2":
        splitPane_horizontal = new SplitPane();
        splitPane_horizontal.getItems().addAll(classTabPane, debugInspectorTabPane, consoleDebugTabPane);
        splitPane_horizontal.setDividerPositions(0.33f, 0.66f);
        borderPane_root.setCenter(splitPane_horizontal);
        break;
    case "debugView3":
        splitPane_horizontal = new SplitPane();
        splitPane_vertical = new SplitPane();
        splitPane_horizontal.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        splitPane_vertical.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        splitPane_horizontal.getItems().addAll(debugInspectorTabPane, consoleDebugTabPane);
        splitPane_vertical.getItems().addAll(classTabPane, splitPane_horizontal);
        borderPane_root.setCenter(splitPane_vertical);
        break;
    }
}

private void changeView(String _id) {
    switch (_id) {
    case "tab_menuPanelStart":
        borderPane_root.setCenter(classTabPane);
        break;
    case "tab_menuPanelDebug":
        selectDebugView(Settings.__getInstance().getDebugViewID());
        break;
    case "tab_menuPanelServer":
        borderPane_root.setCenter(consoleServerTabPane);
        break;
    }
}
```

Here an example:

[Start view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiM2x.jpg)

[Debug view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqDuN.jpg)

Comment: It looks like you are placing the same nodes (e.g. `classTabPane`) into different parents, by making them part of the items list of different `SplitPane` instances, though there's not really sufficiently complete code in your question to know if that's the case. That would violate the rules of the scene graph and significantly confuse the layout.